# multiplicar celdas en jtable y asignar total a una nueva celda en otra columna

Tags: java-swing, jtable

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Necesito si alguien me puede colaborar, la idea es tener un jtable con las siguientes columnas, codigo, descripcion, cantidad, precio, total,  y que desde la celda cantidad al ingresar un valor lo multiplique por el precio y lo asigne a la columna total, agradeceré su ayuda ya que soy nuevo en java.

```
private void TotalPagar() {

    Totalpagar = 0.00;
    int numFila = TableVenta.getRowCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < numFila; i++) {
int cant =Integer.parseInt(TableVenta.getValueAt(i,2).toString());

double precio=Double.parseDouble(TableVenta.getValueAt(i,3).toString());

double cal=Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(TableVenta.getModel().getValueAt(i, 4)));

        Totalpagar = Totalpagar + cal;
    }
    LabelTotal.setText(String.format("%.2f", Totalpagar));
}
```

Comment: Hola Sais, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: Para mostrar un JTable, tienes que tener una matriz de datos, la solución es tan sencilla, como esto: al crear la matriz, realizas la operación que mencionas, y luego instancias la tabla.

Comment: Si la respuesta de un usuario resuelve tu problema, puedes marcala como aceptada, si esta (o un comentario) no resuelve tu problema, pero te ayuda a encontrar la solución, puedes darle un "**flechaParaArriba**", son buenas forma de agradecer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

antes que nada agradecimiento a Ruslan López por su aportacion,[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] mi solución Personal puede que exista otra forma mas sencilla, la idea es tener un jtable con las siguientes columnas, codigo, descripcion, cantidad, precio, total, y que desde la celda cantidad al ingresar un valor lo multiplique por el precio y lo asigne a la columna total.

Bueno en el metodo donde calculo el total pagar al final agregue esta linea de codigo **TableVenta.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", true);**, luego en el evento de mi Jtable Events--Key--KeyReleased llame al metodo **TotalPagar()**, con esos cambios ya logre desde mi jtable en la columna cantidad ingresar valores y que se multiplique por el precio y asigne el valor a la columna total.

private static final int COLUMNA_CANTIDAD=2;

private static final int COLUMNA_PRECIO=3;

private static final int COLUMNA_SUBTOTAL=4;

private void TotalPagar() {

```
    Totalpagar = 0.00;
    int numFila = TableVenta.getRowCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < numFila; i++) {

        int cant = Integer.parseInt(TableVenta.getValueAt(i, COLUMNA_CANTIDAD).toString());
        double precio = Double.parseDouble(TableVenta.getValueAt(i, COLUMNA_PRECIO).toString());
        double subtotalCalculado = cant * precio;

TableVenta.getModel().setValueAt(subtotalCalculado, i, COLUMNA_SUBTOTAL);
Totalpagar += subtotalCalculado;
      
TableVenta.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", true);           
    }
    LabelTotal.setText(String.format("%.2f", Totalpagar));
}
```

//Cambios en el jTable

```
 private void TableVentaKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
    TotalPagar();
}                                     

private void TableVentaKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
    TotalPagar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tienes un error de lógica, total debería de ser cantidad multiplicado por el precio y actualmente estas sumando únicamente el precio

```
 Totalpagar += (cant * cal);
```

Ahora limpiando un poco tu codigo....

```
private static final int COLUMNA_CANTIDAD=2;
private static final int COLUMNA_PRECIO=3;
private static final int COLUMNA_SUBTOTAL=4;
private void TotalPagar() {

    Totalpagar = 0.00;
    int numFila = TableVenta.getRowCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < numFila; i++) {
      int cant =Integer.parseInt(TableVenta.getValueAt(i,COLUMNA_CANTIDAD).toString());

      double precio=Double.parseDouble(TableVenta.getValueAt(i,COLUMNA_PRECIO).toString());

      double subtotalCalculado = cant * precio;

      TableVenta.getModel()
          .setValueAt(i,COLUMNA_SUBTOTAL,subtotalCalculado);    
      Totalpagar += subtotalCalculado;
    }
    LabelTotal.setText(String.format("%.2f", Totalpagar));
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Saludos Ruslan agradecido por tu tiempo y aporte, realize los cambios pero los resultados son los mismos, lo que me esta dando problemas o no encuentro como hacerle es cuando ya el usuario ingresa una fila de registros en la tabla, y desea editar la cantidad que esta se multiplique por el precio y actualize la columna total.

Comment: solamente necesitas llamar a este método en un listener :)

Comment: gracias por tu comentarios fueron de gran ayuda, soy nuevo en java, agregue esta linea de codigo TableVenta.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", true);  y adicional en los eventos keypressed y keyrelease llame al metodo totalPagar y problema resuelto.